# clear resources while call second activity

Tags: android

I have develop one application in which `3 activity.`
in `first activity` there are so `much images`.
in second, `images + sound + background sound`
in third activity `background sound + replay button`

**Problem :** ***now when i am play app in device first time work fine but when i click it replay at second activity give error. i think it is memory problem
 so i have try***

```
intent2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
```

but still not get solve.

**I need code which clear previous data (images and sound) when i am calling second.**

Comment: What is the error? Can you include sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your activity, override `onPause()`. This is called when a new activity is loaded. If the user returns, `onResume()` is called. You can read more about the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) to see when these methods are called.